# Commit error in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am connected to a git repository. Every time I want to commit something, Xcode says "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain error -70.)". After I press ok, I can commit my changes and everything looks fine, but it is annoying. Anybody with a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I am a basic svn user so I am sure there is a better answer but it helped me, the conflict was on my project.xcodeproj file, so I closed XCode, I created a backup of the current project, not sure if snapshots functionality may works due the xcodeproj file is about to be changed and it may crash, I opened the terminal, and I executed the command "svn update" it prompted me:

```
Conflict discovered in 'myProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

I selected 's', then I got

```
  (e)  edit             - change merged file in an editor
  (df) diff-full        - show all changes made to merged file
  (r)  resolved         - accept merged version of file

  (dc) display-conflict - show all conflicts (ignoring merged version)
  (mc) mine-conflict    - accept my version for all conflicts (same)
  (tc) theirs-conflict  - accept their version for all conflicts (same)

  (mf) mine-full        - accept my version of entire file (even non-conflicts)
  (tf) theirs-full      - accept their version of entire file (same)

  (p)  postpone         - mark the conflict to be resolved later
  (l)  launch           - launch external tool to resolve conflict
  (s)  show all         - show this list
```

I selected 'tc' and then I opened my project again and I applied my changes.